# How to do this query in SQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

actor:

```
id  name    gender
1   jack     M
2   jane     F
3   Robert   M
```

film:

```
id   actor_id  movie
1     2         mov1
2     3         mov2
3     3         mov3
```

I want:

```
name     gender
Robert    M
```

I have to extract actor name and his gender who has maximum number of movies.
how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN the tables and GROUP BY the actor.  Then you can sort by the number of movies they are in and pick the biggest one.

```
SELECT name, gender
FROM actor
JOIN film on actor.id = film.actor_id
GROUP BY actor.ID
ORDER BY COUNT(film.id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/415bbd/1